# Comment on a uncommitted change in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, svn

Is there a way to comment an uncommitted change in vs code, so when I send it to review I can write what was that about.

I have to send my code to commit about twice a month and not always I remember what have I done, I can't comment above the line I edited cause my senior can't spend time erasing it.

So it would be perfect if I could do a comment on the uncommitted change inside the vscode.

I tried to use the git branch inside vscode but didn't find a function that solved this problem

Edit: the vscode extension i was talking about is the source control, i think it comes as default

**Clarification:** The OP is using `svn`, not `git`.

Comment: Normally you would do a commit containing said code and write the comment in the commit message.
Do you have a reason to only do a commit 2 times a month? That seems to be against every best practice of git I have ever read :P

Comment: I don't know about VSCode but you said you tried something with Git too. This seems like asking if you can use the filesystem to annotate something that hasn't been saved to disk yet.

Comment: @Kim Well actually I work in a small company, and my boss give me requests and when he got time to review and commit my code we do it, but it's not as frequently as we would like

Comment: You should totally clarify this with them. You can merge more than one commit at a time. You should commit as much as you'd like to. There is always the possibility to rewrite history afterward if need be. Go find a good git tutorial ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Pull Requests to submit code for review or strictly stuck with "Hey, pull my branch and look at this code"? With a Pull Request, you can commit your changes over time, go into the PR, mark it as a Draft, and add comments throughout. When it's ready, your boss can review the code, make their comments, and better track how things are progressing.

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/about-pull-request-reviews

[image: Github pull request with comments.]

This would also unlock the ability to submit multiple changes as you go, creating more minor pull requests that your boss could use to review as they have time.

Comment: Actually we're using svn tortoise to manage the code version, and yeah it's more like "Hey, pull my branch and look at this code" and look at the changes and new code and ask what have you done here.

Comment: Are you using `git` or `svn`?

Comment: svn, sorry i though it would be the same thing

Comment: They're similar in that they're both source control but not the same. Different branching processes. Different underlying architecture. Merging's different. I haven't used `svn` since maybe 2009. IIRC, VSCode defaults to `git`. There's a plugin for `svn`.